# Solving ${dy\over dx} = y - \sin{y}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: Given $${dy\over dx} = y - \sin{y}$$
Show there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that if $|y_0| < \epsilon$, then the solution $y = f(x)$ with $f(0) = y_0$ satisfies $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = 0$$

---

The existence part should be taken care of by employing the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem.

But the solution requires evaluating the integral
$$\int {1\over y - \sin y}dy$$
which I'm pretty sure is a non-elementary integral. I'm having a tough time solving this. Are there any techniques I should use?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha cannot find a result for the integral in terms of standard math functions(including some more complicated ones)

Comment: There is no need to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Have you thought about a Taylor polynomial for the right-hand side?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to evaluate the integral. If $\phi(y) = y-\sin y$ then $|\phi'(y)| \le 2$ for all $y$ so the usual existence & uniqueness theorems apply.

Note that $\phi$ is strictly monotonically increasing and $\phi(0) = 0$.
In particular note that the system is time invariant and $0$ is the **only** equilibrium point, hence the unique solution passing through $0$ is $x \mapsto 0$,

Suppose $y$ is the solution starting from $y(0) >0$. Then $y(x) >0$ for all $x$ (otherwise this would contradict uniqueness of the $x \mapsto 0$ solution). Hence $y'(x) >0$ for all $x$.

Hence
$y$ is strictly increasing and bounded below (by $0$). In particular,
$y^*=\lim_{x \to -\infty} y(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} y'(x) = \phi(y^*) \ge 0$.

I claim that $\phi(y^*) =0$ (and hence $y^* = 0$). If not, then $y'(x) \ge \delta $ for some $\delta>0$ and so $y(x) \le y(0)+\delta x$ which contradicts $y(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

The same reasoning mutatis mutandis applies for $y(0) <0$.